# Can not debug the application after using Security framework to authorization as root

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

A simple Cocoa Application,i could debug it,the breakpoints are fired normal.But after authorization as root using Security Framework, the breakpoints can not be fired again,i could not debug the application again. WHY? What should i do to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open Xcode as sudo first:

```
cd /Developer/Applications
sudo open Xcode
```

Comment: Not work well，but i could sudo open gdb,then attach to the process.

Comment: Yes, use sudo on gdb. It's generally bad to run whole apps with sudo, since that creates a large attack surface on apps which are not hardened. The reason this is necessary should be fairly obvious: if you can debug a process, you have complete control over it. If that process is privileged and you are not, that's a security hole.